# Run class method at end of chain

Tags: php, oop, chain

So this is an `OOP` related question, but I was wondering if it was possible to call a function at the end of a chain, after it's all been run.

This was my code to run before wanting a function to be used explicitly when the chained methods are finished and I want to `print` or `opt` the content:

```
$something = $class('Paramater')->Foo(true)->opt();
```

Whereas, if we remove the end method we're just given the `$this` returned from the `Foo()` function, so:

```
$something = $class('Paramater')->Foo(true);
```

Would return us the actual class variable in `$something`.

What I'd like to happen is at the end of the chain, there might be a `magic method` that's called when the chain is finished.

So, `$class('Parameter')->Foo(true)` would instead return the value of `opt()` like used before, without needing the ending function to close the chain.

It's not so hard to simply add the chain-ending function at the end of a chain, but it helps the code look cleaner and easier to read without this chain ending function being used.

Comment: You might do it in your `Foo()` method: it'd return `opt()` when passed `true`, but do something else (and return something else) for other arg(s) passed.

Comment: Or @cFreed just pass each paramater with an array, index 0 is the method variable, index 1 is `continue_chain_or_not`

Comment: Yes, why not? In fact there are plenty of ways, depending how it's _easily_ appropriate to what the code does in the particular case.

Comment: @cFreed Yeah, exactly. I'm working on a library for my framework and it seems to be a big misconception that people can't simply add the `opt()` function at the end of their chains, so I'm not sure how re-designing my library will be, but thanks for responding `:~)`